# Fibonacci series printing wrong if variables are initialized in different ways

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python from scratch. I'm stuck at a problem i.e. when I'm trying to get a Fibonacci series initializing the variables in the same line I get the right output but when I do it in different lines it doesn't give me the right output can someone please explain me why? Thank you in advance

Working Copy

```
a, b = 0, 1

while a<10:
    print("The value here is", a)
    a, b =b, a+b
```

output: 
('The value here is', 0)
('The value here is', 1)
('The value here is', 1)
('The value here is', 2)
('The value here is', 3)
('The value here is', 5)
('The value here is', 8)

The below code doesn't work

```
a = 0 
b = 1

while a<10: 
    print(a)
    a=b
    b=a+b
```

output:
0
1
2
4
8

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, i.e. a,b = b, a+b the calculation and assignment happens in one go. so, the code right to = will be executed first and then assigned to the parameters left to =

so a will be set to value b and b will be set b + the old value of a but not the new value.

But second code the value of b is calculated after a is updated with the value of b.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you Mr.Ramesh. Appreciate that! :)

Comment: You are welcome Abhi.. Could you please up vote my answer

Comment: it doesn't allow me to vote, this was my first question and I've just signed up to stack overflow.

Comment: OK.. I am new here too.. Didn't know.. Thank you Abhi